# Quickbooks Integration Making Deposits

Tags: php, quickbooks-online, qbxml

I have a php web app that is integrated with quickbooks online.  I am able to add invoices and make payments to them.  Now I am trying to create a deposit for the payments.  Here is the xml:

```
<?qbxml version="2.0" ?>
<QBXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonTicketRq>
            <ClientDateTime>' . date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s') . '</ClientDateTime>
            <SessionTicket>' . $this->session . '</SessionTicket>
            <Language>English</Language>
            <AppID>' . $this->application_id . '</AppID>
            <AppVer>1</AppVer>
        </SignonTicketRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <DepositAddRq requestID="0">
            <DepositAdd>
                <DepositToAccountRef>
                    <FullName>Premier Checking</FullName>
                </DepositToAccountRef>
                <DepositLineAdd>
                    <PaymentTxnID>' . $txnid . '</PaymentTxnID>
                </DepositLineAdd>
            </DepositAdd>
        </DepositAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I get the following response back from the request:
   `<DepositAddRs requestID="0" statusCode="1030" statusMessage="Not supported" statusSeverity="Error"/>`

Is there something wrong with the xml?  Also, how would I include multiple payments in one deposit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

QBXML for QBOE is being deprecated and you should be looking at the QB API for making connections to QBO.

Here are details on the QBXML deprecation:
https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/12/20/migration-details-quickbooks-online-sdk-to-quickbooks-online-rest-api-v3

Here is a sample for the desktop to connect to QBO:
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/OAuthHangoutSamples

DepositAdd is not supported in QBXML.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Looking at the documentation, Is the a add deposit method in api?